# How to listen socket as IEnumerable?

Tags: c#, .net, sockets

In following code I can subscribe to socket and receive messages. Messages are received in some IO thread.

```
var subscription = SubscribeToStreamAsync( msg => { } ).Result;
...
Unsubscribe( subscription );
```

I want to listen those messages in usual `foreach` loop. So, I need to route messages in my thread and return stream as `IEnumerable`.

```
foreach(var item in GetStreamAsync().Result) {
    if (item == ...) break;
}
```

Could I do it via `System.Collections.Concurrent`?

And I don't want to use `System.Reactive`.

Comment: For starters, you shouldn't be using `.Result` unless you want to potentially [deadlock your code](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html), you should be using asynchrony with `async` implementations. `foreach` will process items in an enumerable, it will not sit and listen to events. Why don't you want to use `System.Reactive`?

Comment: Sounds like `IAsyncEnumerable` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.iasyncenumerable-1?view=netcore-3.0&viewFallbackFrom=netframework-4.7.2 which is under way

Comment: @ColinM 1) I tried to use ```async``` but without ```IAsyncEnumerable``` it's not always possible. Synchronous code is also works. 2) I want ```foreach``` to sit and listen to events. I.e. I want ```foreach``` sleeps thread until next message is received or error is happened. 3) I don't like ```System.Reactive```. Its code is looking very confusing.

Comment: `foreach` is not design to sit and listen, what you're doing is getting all of the events and then process them in a `foreach`. You'd have to design your code in such a way that it steps out and back into the loop to process the next events. `System.Reactive` is ideal for what you're looking to do here, and while the code looks confusing the first time - that's where learning material comes in.

Comment: Sync-over-async is a bad pattern you should not use. It always involves buffering, an at worst invisible and potentially unlimited buffering (Rx will happily provide such invisible buffering when you use `.ToEnumerable()`, for example). It's certainly possible to use synchronous code to read a byte stream obtained from a socket: it's called `NetworkStream`. Just use that (or the more convenient `TcpClient`). If you want a higher-level API on top of that that interprets the bytes, write your own enumerator.

Comment: Jeroen Mostert, now I'm getting many data via http requests. Because for one request I can get only limited count of data, I'm forced to send many requests. I wait for each request and yield its result. User code is sending requests and getting data via iterating the ```IEnumerable```. Of course it's blocking thread. But I do not see any reason why this is bad. That works great!

Comment: Jeroen Mostert, I want to do the same for the socket. Now I see only one problem: when consumer is slower than producer.

Comment: Is the socket using UDP and sending data as UDP messages? If not, the situation is not comparable to executing HTTP requests in parallel: TCP is a stream-based protocol and you can only read the bytes as a sequential stream. (It's technically possible to have multiple read requests pending, but this is pointless as you will no longer be able to make sense of the data returned that way). Asynchronous code only helps reduce threads waiting on I/O in this case; it will not achieve parallelism.

Comment: To be clear: a blocking thread is not a problem in and of itself. The problem is a thread that's *not* blocking and merrily reading data consumers are not prepared to handle. This requires an explicit buffer in between, which is fine, as long as you actually *implement* such a buffer (which you can do with existing mechanisms, like `BlockingCollection` or `BufferBlock`). What's not fine is explicitly waiting on the asynchronous results themselves; that means the whole asynchronous mechanism is pointless and could as well have been synchronous.

Comment: Jeroen Mostert, I'm using third party library and I don't know what protocol is used. I just want to convert events into IEnumerable. I will learn ```BlockingCollection``` and ```BufferBlock```. Hope it will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done the following way.

Only I'm afraid that thread will freeze if any problem with socket/server happens.

```
var collection = new BlockingCollection<object>();
var subscription = SubscribeToStreamAsync().Result;
try {
    var enumerable = collection.GetConsumingEnumerable();
    foreach (var item in enumerable) {
        yield return item;
    }
} finally {
    // foreach or stream is completed
    Unsubscribe( subscription ).Wait();
}
```